# Remove timestamp from Xcode debugger output

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have searched in Google but haven't found any way to remove the timestamp from the XCODE Debugger's output.

```
{
  [Session started at 2011-07-22 12:30:17 +0530.]
  ***2011-07-22 12:30:17.435 obj-compose-obj-c-1[3070:10b]*** *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x104a20 of class NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
  Stack: (0x946eef4f 0x945fb432)
  ***2011-07-22 12:30:17.437 obj-compose-obj-c-1[3070:10b]***  1 fl I am the best tire from MRF 

  The Debugger has exited with status 0.

 }
```

I want to remove it as I need a clear output.
The actual output is somehow messy.

Comment: @satya, writing in CAPS in considered rude. Read [here](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070718202452AAHIRQL). Please follow standard rules.

Comment: @satya I tried to clean up your question a bit to help you get better answers. Please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for guidelines on posting questions here.

Comment: @Mitch, Kaj: He’s obviously new here. With your reputation, wouldn’t it be better to edit the question and explain the rules, just like Marnix did?

Comment: @Mitch: No. But more reputation = more power = more responsibility. It’s much more responsible to guide new posters rather than to scorn them.

Comment: @zoul: I'd hardly call that scorn. More light-hearted humour

Comment: @Mitch: OK, sorry if I read that wrong. Still I think it’s more constructive to do the other thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `#define` and some C99 macro magic, as described [here](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/debugging/the-evolution-of-a-replacement-for-nslog) to fix this. Using this technique, I was able to achieve just the logging capabilities I wanted, as a drop in solution.